# Run reports from Java application on a Crystal Reports Server and export as PDF programmatically

Tags: java, pdf, web, crystal-reports

As per the deployment model in one of our Java web applications, we have the SAP Crystal Reports Server 2011 that hosts and runs all the reports based on requests from the application.

I would like to know if it is possible to request for a report to be run on the Crystal server from the Java web application and export it as a PDF so that the application can send it back to the browser.

We need to run the reports on the Crystal server and not within the Java web application so that the latter is not loaded too much and hence would like to take this approach.

Comment: Are the files containing the reports saved in a directory? If so, then is it local ?

Comment: Need some answers to these comments shyam .

Comment: Hi @DarkKnight! I haven't been able to logon for the last couple of days and hence the delay in responding. The answer to your query: "We are planning to have the reports in the reports repository of Crystal Server and not locally within the Java web application server".

Comment: Can you access the report repository from local ?